# How do I add fields to a layer attribute table .created by CSV import into QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have added a layer from a delimited text (csv) file.  I now wish to add the usual X, Y and Rotation fields to allow me to move and rotate the layer labels.  However, it doesn't seem possible to edit the attribute table as the edit icon is greyed out for this table.

Can I somehow overcome this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to save it to a format with edit support (csv is read only). Try saving the layer as a shapefile or geopackage and you should then be able to add columns.